# Missing type name after '['

Tags: powershell, types, casting

I'm trying to dynamically set the Type Name on a function:

Currently this is the line I'm working on -

```
$ace.AccessBits = ([MVPSI.JAMS.CredentialRights] $a.Value)
```

What I want to be able to do is dynamically change the Type Name so have something like this:

```
$typeName = "MVPSI.JAMS.CredentialRights"
$ace.AccessBits = ([$typeName]) $a.Value)
```

That doesn't work however and I get the following failure:

```
Missing type name after '['.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingTypename
```

Comment: If you came here looking due to a Python **subprocess** error, the problem is a space in the command, make sure you `'comma','delimit','all','spaces'.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-as` operator to convert an input to a type whose name is stored in a string:

```
$ace.AccessBits = $a.Value -as $typeName
```